# How to set @param to method in spring data repository

Tags: java, spring-data, h2

I am using spring data with embedded H2.
I have create this method:

```
public interface PaletteRepository extends CrudRepository<Palette, String> {
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value="INSERT INTO PALETTE SELECT * FROM CSVREAD(:file)", nativeQuery = true)
    void initDataPalette(@Param("file") String file);
}
```

but file param is all the time not set or null and I get this

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Parameter "fileName" is not set; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO PALETTE SELECT * FROM CSVREAD(?)
```

note that work :

```
@Query(value="INSERT INTO PALETTE SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('/file')", nativeQuery = true)enter code here
```

Comment: the error says `fileName` and none of your code includes this. We must be missing something in your code sample. Please show us some code containing `fileName`, it must come from somewhere...

Comment: I resolved my problem by using JDBC statement. I think hibernate not managed this request.